# Fed auth cookie decrypt fails in load balanced environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, forms-authentication, wif

I have 2 web servers behind a load balancer. I have a separate STS (Secure token service app with WIF) application in a different VM.

When user tries to login, user enters organisation in the login page in the web application, which will redirect the user (home realm discovery happens here) to STS application to enter username and password. STS communicates with ADFS server during the login process. Once the user click sign in from the STS application, secure token is created and redirected to the web application which creates a forms authentication cookie and redirect to the home page.

This works perfectly fine. When user navigate to different pages in the website suddenly the user signs out. This happens when the load balancer redirects to the other server (if my log in happen with Server A, and as long as the requests are pointing to Server A it's fine. But once my requests are directed to Server B by the load balancer, I get signed out).

When I run the application in non-STS mode (with just forms authentication), it works fine in the above scenario (user does not sign out when load balancer sending requests to both servers). Both the web servers have same copy of the asp.net MVC web app with same machine keys etc.

So it should be an issue somehow related to STS. Forms authentication cookie stores the "user id", a guid, to load the session variables. As per application logs, once the request is sent to the server which is not the server used to login, it does not recognize the user ID (as guid empty) from the cookie. I am new to STS domain. Here I am sharing the cookie details displayed in the dev tools.

What is happening here? Is it that "FedAuth cookies" were unable to decrypted by a server which they were initially created web server? Please help!!!

Cookies after logged in,
[image]

Cookies when redirecting from STS application to the web application in sign in, 
[image]

Applications are hosted in Azure environment

Comment: Fed auth cookie stores name/role and email.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that both of the servers behind th eloadbalancer should use the same machinekey.  This is used for session cookies.
This can be done by changing the setting the keys and changing the sessionsecurity tokenhandler :

```
            <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

Comment: Can you tell me where to add this config? is it inside microsoft.IdentityModel block?

Comment: Microsoft.IdentityModel is the old section, in .Net 4.5 this has been replaced by 
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
...
 <securityTokenHandlers> 
...
 <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </securityTokenHandlers> 
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>

Comment: I am using microsoft.identitymodel in the project. Is there a similar setting for microsoft.identitymodel?